# Divide people to several groups

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-partition

In how many ways can five people be divided into several groups?

(Number of member can be 1 to 5)

One person can't be in two groups at the same time.

Also, everyone have to join any groups.

---

I think, I should using the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Is this right?

Comment: A set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets. Is this useful?

Comment: You want to look up *Bell numbers*.

Comment: Bell number is a sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind, right? You mean using the stirling numbers of the second kind is correct in this problem?

Comment: I mean using the Bell numbers is correct in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ define $n$ groups, with $v_i$ people in $i$'th group, where $5\geq n\geq1$ and $5\geq v_i>0$. We say $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=m$ to define the $m$ ways this grouping can be performed. WLOG we assume that $v_i\leq v_{i+1}$.

For example: if we split 5 people into 3 groups then we have only these two options: $(1,1,3)$ and $(1,2,2)$.

These two are obvious $(1,1,1,1,1)=(5)=1$.

Notice that $(v_1, v_2)={5\choose v_1}={5\choose v_2}$, basically when we have only 2 groups, we need to calculate number of ways we can choose $v_1$ (or $v_2$) people out of 5.

Thus $(1,4)={5\choose 1}={5\choose 4}=5$, and $(2,3)={5\choose 2}={5\choose 3}=10$.

For $(1,1,3)$ we only look into all ways 3 people can be chosen out of 5, and same for $(1,1,1,2)$,

thus $(1,1,3)=(1,1,1,2)={5\choose 3}={5\choose 2}=10$.

Lastly, $(1,2,2)=5\times3=15$.

$\mathrm{TOTAL}=52$ ways.

Sorry for the mess up writing, I hope this might help you to get a general formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I understand your explanation.

Comment: There are only $15$, not $30$, partitions coming from $(1,2,2)$. Five ways to choose the $1$, then look at any one of the remaining four people, you can match that person up with any of three others, so, $5\times3=15$. Makes the total $52$, not $67$. This agrees with tabulations of Bell numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the correction, I have edited that part